# Separate JavaScript reference for specific element in MVC

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I have an MVC application and there are multiple master pages.
Some master pages are running on aspx version and using an older version of bootstrap, bootstrap Switch, bootstrap slider, etc. Some are running on cshtml version and using the latest version of bootstrap, bootstrap Switch, and bootstrap slider. Now I have created a partial view which will be used as a plugin on all the master pages and I have used the latest version of bootstrap and the bootstrap slider for that.
Now there are multiple version of CSS and JS on the pages , So how we can restrict the use of specific JS or CSS references to the specific elements?

For example- Js and CSS referred to on this plugin should not impact the functionality of the existing page.
I have found the solution for the CSS using the Shadow DOM element but am not able to find anything for the JS references.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.